# How would i display a merge sort algorithm visually through an array with swaps?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am having trouble using my algorithm to try and visually display the process of merge sort. For my past arrays I have been able to use swaps with algos like Bubblesort etc., but merge sort is harder since its a recursive algorithm. I was thinking of pushing the elements in my merge function to another array but it does not return in sorted order and comparing against the sorted array at the end is not true mergesort. if anyone can help me that would be amazing. Here's my algorithm as it stands now:

```
export const doMergeSort = (array) => {

  function merge(leftArr, rightArr){
    const output = [];
    let leftIndex = 0; 
    let rightIndex = 0; 

    while(leftIndex < leftArr.length && rightIndex < rightArr.length){
       
      const leftEl = leftArr[leftIndex];
      const rightEl = rightArr[rightIndex];

      if(leftEl < rightEl){
        output.push(leftEl);
        
        leftIndex++;
      }
      else{
        output.push(rightEl);
       
        rightIndex++;
      }
    }
   
    
    
    return ( [...output, ...leftArr.slice(leftIndex), ...rightArr.slice(rightIndex)]); 
  };
  
  function mergeSort(array) {

    
    if(array.length <= 1){
      
      return array;
    }
    
    const middleIndex = Math.floor(array.length / 2);
    const leftArr = array.slice(0, middleIndex);
    const rightArr = array.slice(middleIndex, array.length);
    
    return merge(
      mergeSort(leftArr),
      mergeSort(rightArr),
    ); 

  }

  return mergeSort(array);
}

export default mergeSortAnimations;
```

Answer (score 0):

This is something that I did, a while back to achieve this. Used a single object to keep track of the array at each function level all wrapped in a closure-like environment. Also used generators so that, I can pause between each swap.

```
const getMergeSortGenerator = (object: SortingVisualizerController) => {
  // Doing this so that I can pause at any swap for a while using
  // setTimeout, or setInterval
  function* mergeSortGenerator(start: number, end: number) {
    if (start === end) {
      return;
    }

    const mid = Math.floor((start + end) / 2);

    // Merge sort on first half
    for (const _ of mergeSortGenerator(start, mid)) {
      yield;
    }

    // Merge sort on second half
    for (const _ of mergeSortGenerator(mid + 1, end)) {
      yield;
    }

    // Merge both the halves
    for (const _ of merge(start, mid, mid + 1, end)) {
      yield;
    }

    // Plot array after each merge.
    object.plotArray();
  }


  // Standard merge algorithm
  function* merge(start1: number,
                  end1: number,
                  start2: number,
                  end2: number) {

    const newArray = [];  // Why? Explained below
    let index1 = start1;
    let index2 = start2;

    // Keep merging while the both sub-arrays have elements
    while (index1 <= end1 && index2 <= end2) {
      if (object.array[index1] < object.array[index2]) {
        newArray.push(object.array[index1++]);
      } else {
        newArray.push(object.array[index2++]);
      }

      // Mark the swap color as red
      object.color[index1] = object.color[index2] = "red";

      // Plot the swap
      plotArray(newArray, start1, index1, index2, end1);

      // Reset the swap color
      object.color[index1] = object.color[index2] = "white";
      yield;
    }

    // If first sub-array has elements left, just add
    // them directly
    while (index1 <= end1) {
      newArray.push(object.array[index1++]);
      object.color[index1] = "red";
      plotArray(newArray, start1, index1, index2, end1);
      object.color[index1] = "white";
      yield;
    }

    // If second sub-array has elements left, just add
    // them directly
    while (index2 <= end2) {
      newArray.push(object.array[index2++]);
      object.color[index2 - 1] = "red";
      plotArray(newArray, start1, index1, index2, end1);
      object.color[index2 - 1] = "white";
      yield;
    }

    // I could not do this in-place because doing each swap
    // in-place would mean that, I have to shift other elements
    // by 1 to left and that would be a bit tricky to handle.
    // So, I managed swaps in the different array, and when the merge
    // was completed, I substituted the swaps back in the original
    // array.
    newArray.forEach((value, index) => {
      object.array[index + start1] = value;
    });
  }

  function plotArray(
    array: number[],
    startOfFirstHalf: number,
    index1: number,     // First half sorted till this index
    index2: number,     // Second half sorted till this index
    endOfFirstHalf: number,
  ) {
    // Need this because I am using an intermediate array to
    // perform the merge.
    const visualizingArray = [
      ...object.array.slice(0, startOfFirstHalf),
      ...array.slice(0, array.length),
      ...object.array.slice(index1, endOfFirstHalf + 1),
      ...object.array.slice(index2, object.array.length),
    ];

    object.plotArray(visualizingArray);
  }

  return mergeSortGenerator(0, object.array.length - 1);
};


export default class SortingVisualizerController {
  arraySize = 166;
  minimumHeightOfPipe = 2;

  selectedSortAlgorithm = "merge";
  animationRunning = false;

  constructor(canvasEl: HTMLCanvasElement) {
    this.color = [];
    this.array = [];

    // Canvas is just a class that has some utility functions for drawing on the canvas.
    // Find more about it here: https://github.com/vighnesh153/canvas-api-illustrations/blob/master/src/models/canvas.ts
    this.canvas = new Canvas(canvasEl);
    
    this.randomizeArray();
  }

  isArraySorted() {
    let prev = -Infinity;
    let isSorted = true;

    this.array.forEach((value) => {
      if (value < prev) {
        isSorted = false;
      }
      prev = value;
    });

    return isSorted;
  }

  startAnimation() {
    if (this.isArraySorted()) {
      return;
    }

    this.animationRunning = true;
    
    const generatorObject = getMergeSortGenerator(this);
    const timer = 30;

    this.interval = setInterval(() => {
      // Keep yielding, so that we pause after each swap
      if (generatorObject.next().done) {
        this.stopAnimation();
      }
    }, timer);
  }

  clearBackground() {
    const {width, height} = this.canvas;
    this.canvas.drawFilledRect(0, 0, width, height, "black");
  }

  generateRandomArray() {
    this.array = [];
    this.color = [];
    
    const maxHeight = this.canvas.height - 50;
    const { floor, random } = Math;

    for (let i = 0; i < this.arraySize; i++) {
      this.array.push(floor(random() * maxHeight) + 20);
      this.color.push("white");
    }
  }

  plotArray(array?: number[]) {
    if (array === undefined) {
      array = this.array;
    }
    this.clearBackground();
    array.forEach((height: number, index: number) => {
      const x = index * 3;
      const y = this.canvas.height - value;
      const width = 2;
      const color = this.color[index];
      
      this.canvas.drawFilledRect(x, y, width, 
        height + this.minimumHeightOfPipe, color);
    });
  }

  randomizeArray() {
    this.generateRandomArray();
    this.plotArray();
  }

  stopAnimation() {
    this.animationRunning = false;
    clearInterval(this.interval);
    this.resetColor();
    this.plotArray();
  }

  resetColor() {
    this.color.forEach((v, i) => {
      this.color[i] = "white";
    });
  }
}
```